# How to put javascript variable inside url() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.7

I've been twisting around my code for a couple of hours now but no luck in getting the right approach of putting a javascript variable inside laravel `url()`. The variable is taken as a string whenever I placed it as a parameter inside the url(). Below is my code. Please help.

**javascript file**

```
function generateSchedule( id, loan_type ){

          var txt_url;           

          if( loan_type == "Business" ){
            txt_url = 'addamortbusinessloan'; 
          }else{
            txt_url = 'addamortization';
          }


          $.post('{{ url("'+txt_url+'") }}', {'loanId':id}, function(data){


       },"json");

    }
```

This is not working `{{ url("'+txt_url+'") }}`. I have been twisting the quotes placement but no luck at all.  The result of this is `http://localhost:8000/txt_url`. I want it to be like this `http://localhost:8000/addamortbusinessloan` or `http://localhost:8000/addamortization`

Comment: _putting a javascript variable inside laravel url()._ you can't this way. Your code above is a php template, I assume. But `generateSchedule` is called in the browser. So that txt_url variable doesn't exist in JavaScript at all, which is why your template engine renders the static value you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to put it in commas it works fine without comma. Check this

```
function generateSchedule( id, loan_type ){

          var txt_url;           

          if( loan_type == "Business" ){
            txt_url = "addamortbusinessloan"; 
          }else{
            txt_url = "addamortization";
          }

        var base_url="http://localhost:8000/"

        $.post( base_url+txt_url, {'loanId':id}, function( data ) {

         }, "json");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this blade directive to export variables to JS the easy way: `spatie/laravel-blade-javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't but if you need you can define global variable into your app.blade file like this

```
var BASE_URL='{{url('')}}'
</script>
```

Or another way you can define it in meta tag in `head` like this:

and in your javascript file you can get it by jquery
`$('meta[name=base_url]').attr('content')`

Answer (score -1):

```
function generateSchedule( id, loan_type ){

    var txt_url;

    if( loan_type == "Business" ){
        txt_url = '/addamortbusinessloan';
    }else{
        txt_url = '/addamortization';
    }

    var url = "{{ url('') }}" + txt_url;

    console.log(url);

    $.post(url, {'loanId':id}, function(data){


    },"json");

}
```